# Queuing delays when using async/await

Tags: async-await, queue

How to avoid queuing delays when using async/await?

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   await SomeFunction(i)
}
// 1, 2, 3
```

This queing driving me nuts especially when working with different APIs, but I don't want to give up on using super convinient `await` and returns to this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   SomeFunction(i)
   .then(i => {

   })
}
// 2, 1, 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put all the `Promise`s into an array, and then `await` them all at once with `Promise.all`:

```
var promises = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  promises.push(SomeFunction(i));
}
await Promise.all(promises);
```